# Node.js Drag and Drop Support Windows

Tags: node.js, batch-file

I'm using node.js as a scripting language locally on my machine.

Is it possible to implement drag and drop support in node.js using either .bat's or another technique that implements drag and drop support.

**Downvoters please leave comments**

Comment: server-side drag&drop? serverside hash-bang?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by server-side drag&drop, or server-side hash-bang. Both of those things are client-side terms..

Comment: @KevinB Local drag and drop then ignore the hash-bang part.

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly you are trying to do or what your answer code does, but i'll give you the benefit of the doubt for now.

Comment: @KevinB Save the code as test.bat.  Drag and drop a file on top of the application.  Wait to see what happens.

Comment: Maybe, reword the question to: "How can i have a node.js application process a file by dragging that file on top of the application shortcut"? that would at least make your intent crystal clear, if i'm understanding the intent properly

Comment: You want a comment with my downvote? Fine: your question is unclear, your intent is equally unclear, your title isn't a summary of the question (or a complete sentence for that matter), you've shown no attempt at research, and _why in God's name are you using node.js as a local scripting language when it's meant for web pages_?! Additionally, your answer reads like you meant to sign in with a different account. Finally, I don't respect any question that demands a justification of downvotes. You have over 5,000 rep. Frankly, I expected more from you.

Comment: @SomethingDark I answered my own question.

Comment: @William - And there's nothing wrong with that. It's just the way you worded it made it wound like you were explaining it to the person who asked the question. And the rest of my points still stand; it's not a very good question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple save the following as a .bat.  Then you can drag and drop files onto the script.  Simple paste the data after the first four lines.

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" -p "eval(String(require(\"fs\").readFileSync(process.argv[1])).split(\"\n\").splice(3).join(\"\n\"));''" %0 %*
exit

var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;

child = exec("C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\nb.nb",function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error != null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});

/*
var fs = require('fs');
fs.stat(process.argv[2], function (err, stats) {
    console.log(stats.size);
  });
*/
```